# Clickable regions on an image map

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am building an app for a festival. On thing is that I show a scrollable image (the festival area) where I must be able to zoom in and out and scroll too it. You can see an example image below.

[image]

Like you can see over here, there are three stages: (Wablief?!, Marquee, The shelter).
Now I should be able to click on those stages. When I click on a stage a tableview should pop up as a modalView with the artists in it.

Now my question is: how can I achieve that? Keep in mind that this image should be scrollable and zoomable. So working with `UIButtons` is not an option, I think.

Comment: do u know the frame of this 3 stage?

Comment: This is just an example I downloaded on my iPhone, I need to do this for another festival. But don't now how to start.

Comment: ya I get that but in your app do u know which fram u want to make clickable?

Comment: Just the stages should be clickable, so these are my frames i think.

Comment: but you should know the X, Y width and height of that stage.

Comment: Oké but lets say I got a giant image from the whole festival area from my designer. And now my job is to make those stages clickable. Than I need define those X and Y regions of each stage right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22892/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-crdave)

Answer (score 0):

Have a scrollview with the large scrollable image in the background.

Create UIImageViews for all tappable objects you need.

Add them to the scrollview as subviews at appropriate locations.

Add tap gestures to all such image views.

I hope this would work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just have gone through this. I added a series of transparent UIButtons. Each button has a tag, so all of the buttons can be identified in a single method. You can then take actions based on the sender.tag. I had 100 buttons. It was laborious but it works.